# how to draw plate indices in graphical model by tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I made my Hierarchical model with tikz by following code:

```
‎‎\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}‎
‎\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}‎
‎\usepackage{amsmath}‎
‎\usepackage{amsfonts}‎
‎\usepackage{amssymb}‎
‎\usepackage{color}‎
‎\usepackage{graphicx}‎
‎\usepackage{multirow}‎
‎‎‎\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}‎
‎\usepackage{tikz}‎
‎\usetikzlibrary{shapes,‎arrows, fit‎‎‎}‎‎
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}‎

% ‎Define block styles‎
‎\tikzstyle{response} = [cloud‎, ‎circle‎, ‎draw‎, ‎fill=blue!20‎, 
    ‎text width=‎8‎em‎, ‎text centered‎,  ‎minimum height=3em]‎

‎\tikzstyle{level1} = [cloud‎, ‎circle‎, ‎draw‎, ‎fill=green!10‎, 
    ‎text width=‎7‎em‎, ‎text centered‎,  ‎minimum height=2em]‎    

‎\tikzstyle{level2} = [cloud‎, ‎circle‎, ‎draw‎, ‎fill=red!10‎, 
    ‎text width=6em‎, ‎text centered‎,  ‎minimum height=2em]  ‎‎
    ‎
 ‎\tikzstyle{‎level3‎} = [cloud‎, ‎circle‎, ‎draw‎, ‎fill=yellow!10‎, 
   ‎text width=‎5‎‎em‎, ‎text centered‎,  ‎minimum height=2em]  ‎‎‎
    ‎
‎\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=‎stealth]‎‎
\tikzstyle{a} = [rectangle, draw, minimum height=1‎3‎‎‎‎‎‎em, minimum width=‎3‎‎0em]‎‎
\tikzstyle{‎b‎} = [rectangle, draw, minimum height=‎2‎6‎‎‎em, minimum width=‎50‎‎em]‎‎
\tikzstyle{‎c} = [rectangle, draw, minimum height=‎4‎7‎‎‎‎‎em, minimum width=‎45‎‎em]‎‎‎
‎\author{Ehsan Masoudi}‎
‎\begin{document}‎


‎%‎\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = ‎2‎‎cm‎, ‎‎thick‎, every node/.style={scale=0.‎7‎}, ‎‎auto]‎‎
%align = flush centera‎
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.‎7‎, every node/.style={transform shape}]‎
% ‎Place nodes‎
 % ‎\node [response] (resp) {$y_{(pij)} \sim Wiener(\alpha_{(p)}‎, ‎\beta‎, ‎\tau_{(pij)}‎, ‎\delta_{(pij)})$};‎

 ‎\node [response] (resp) {$y_{(pij)}$};‎
‎%%level1‎    
\node [level1‎, ‎above = ‎1.5‎‎‎cm of  resp] (alpha) {$\alpha_{(p)} \sim N(\mu_{\alpha}‎, ‎\sigma^2_{\alpha})$}‎;‎‎
‎\node [level1‎, ‎left =‎ ‎.7cm‎ of  resp] (tau) {$\tau_{(pij)} \sim N(\theta_{(p)}‎, ‎\chi_{(p)})$};‎  
‎\node [level1‎, ‎right = .7cm of resp] (delta) {$\delta_{(pij)} \sim N(\nu_{(pi)}‎, ‎\eta_{(p)})$};‎

‎%%level2‎ 
‎‎‎‎\node [‎level2‎‎, ‎above left =‎ ‎1.5‎cm and ‎-‎.‎4‎‎cm‎ of alpha] (‎mu‎-‎alpha) ‎{‎‎$‎\mu_‎\‎alpha ‎\sim U(.01, ‎3‎)‎‎$‎}‎;‎
‎\node [level2‎, ‎above right =‎ ‎1.5‎cm and ‎-‎.‎4‎cm of alpha] (‎sig‎ma-alpha)‎ {‎‎$‎\sigma‎_‎\alpha \sim U(.‎0‎0‎0‎1, ‎2‎‎)‎$‎}‎;‎‎
‎
‎\node [level2‎, ‎above ‎left = ‎3‎cm ‎and ‎0.5‎‎cm‎ of ‎tau‎] ‎(‎theta)‎ {‎$‎‎‎\theta_{(p)‎} \sim N(\mu_‎\t‎heta‎, ‎\sigma_\theta)‎$‎‎‎‎‎}‎‎‎;‎‎
‎\node [level2‎, ‎below ‎= ‎5.5‎‎‎cm‎  ‎‎of ‎tau‎] ‎(‎chi)‎ {‎$‎‎‎\chi_{(p)‎} \sim N(\mu_‎\chi‎‎, ‎\sigma_‎\chi)‎‎‎‎$‎}‎‎‎;‎‎
‎‎\node [level2‎, ‎above ‎right = ‎3‎cm ‎and ‎.4cm‎ ‎‎of ‎delta‎‎] ‎(‎eta)‎ {‎$‎\eta‎_{(p)‎} \sim N(\mu_‎\eta‎‎‎, ‎\sigma_‎\eta)‎‎‎‎$‎}‎‎‎;‎‎
‎\node [level2‎, ‎below = ‎1‎‎‎‎‎‎cm ‎‎of ‎delta‎‎] ‎(‎nu‎)‎ {‎$‎\nu‎‎_{(pi)‎}‎‎‎\sim N(\mu_‎{\nu(i)}‎‎, ‎\sigma_‎{\nu(i)})$‎}‎‎‎;‎‎
‎
‎‎‎‎\node [‎level3‎‎‎, ‎above left =‎ ‎1.‎5‎‎cm and ‎-‎.‎4‎cm‎ of ‎theta‎] (‎mu‎-‎theta) ‎{‎‎$‎\mu_‎\theta‎‎ \sim U(.0‎‎1, ‎1‎‎)‎$‎}‎;‎
‎\node [level3‎, ‎above right =‎ ‎1.5‎cm and ‎-‎.‎4‎cm‎ of theta] (‎sig‎ma-‎thet‎a)‎ {‎‎$‎\sigma‎_‎‎\theta \sim U(.0‎0‎0‎‎1, ‎.‎25‎)‎‎$‎}‎;‎‎
‎
‎‎‎‎‎\node [‎level3‎‎‎, ‎above right = ‎.7‎‎‎‎‎cm ‎and ‎4‎.2‎‎‎‎‎‎cm‎ ‎‎‎‎‎of ‎nu‎‎] (‎mu‎-‎nu) ‎{‎‎$‎\mu_{‎\nu(i)‎} ‎‎\sim U(-5, 5)‎$‎}‎;‎
‎\node [level3‎, ‎right =‎ ‎4‎‎cm ‎‎‎ of nu] (‎sig‎ma-nu)‎ {‎‎$‎\sigma‎_‎‎{\nu‎(i)}\sim U(.0001, ‎3‎‎)‎$‎}‎;‎‎
‎
‎‎‎‎‎\node [‎level3‎‎‎, ‎above left =‎ ‎1.5‎cm and ‎-‎.‎4‎cm of ‎eta‎] (‎mu‎-‎eta) ‎{‎‎$‎\mu_‎\‎‎eta = ‎3.5‎‎$‎}‎;‎
‎\node [level3‎, ‎above right =‎ ‎‎1.5‎cm and -.4cm‎ of eta] (‎sig‎ma-eta)‎ {‎‎$‎\sigma‎_‎‎\eta = ‎3.5‎‎$‎}‎;‎‎‎

‎‎‎‎‎\node [‎level3‎‎‎, ‎below‎ left = ‎‎‎1‎.5‎‎‎cm ‎and ‎-‎.‎4‎‎‎‎‎‎cm‎ of ‎chi‎] (‎mu‎-‎chi) ‎{‎‎$‎\mu_‎‎\chi = ‎.35‎$‎}‎;‎
‎\node [level3‎, ‎below right = ‎1.5‎cm ‎and ‎-‎.4‎cm‎ of chi] (‎sig‎ma-chi)‎ {‎‎$‎\sigma‎_‎‎\chi = ‎.125‎‎$‎}‎;‎‎

 ‎%‎‎\node‎ [above right =0.75cm and 0cm of ‎theta‎] {CGPA} edge (student)‎;‎
‎
‎
%level1
\draw [arrow] ‎(‎mu-theta‎) ‎-- ‎(theta)‎;
‎\draw [arrow] ‎(‎sigma‎-theta‎) ‎-- ‎(theta)‎;‎‎
‎
\draw [arrow] ‎(‎mu-alpha‎) ‎-- ‎(alpha)‎;
‎\draw [arrow] ‎(‎sigma‎-alpha‎) ‎-- ‎(alpha)‎;‎‎
‎
‎\draw [‎thick, dashed, ->‎]‎ ‎(‎mu-‎eta‎‎) ‎-- ‎(eta)‎;
‎\draw [‎thick, dashed, ->‎] ‎(‎sigma‎-eta‎) ‎-- ‎(eta)‎;‎‎
‎
‎\draw [arrow] ‎(‎mu-‎nu‎‎‎) ‎-- ‎(‎nu‎)‎;
‎\draw [arrow] ‎(‎sigma‎-nu‎) ‎-- ‎(nu)‎;‎‎
‎
‎\draw [‎thick, dashed, ->‎] ‎(‎mu-‎chi‎‎‎‎) ‎-- ‎(‎chi‎‎)‎;
‎\draw  [‎thick, dashed, ->‎]‎‎(‎sigma‎-chi‎) ‎-- ‎(chi)‎;‎‎‎‎‎‎
‎‎
%level2‎
‎‎\draw [arrow] ‎(‎‎chi‎) ‎-- ‎(‎tau‎)‎;‎‎
‎‎\draw [arrow] ‎(‎‎theta‎‎) ‎-- ‎(‎tau‎)‎;‎‎
‎
‎‎\draw [arrow] ‎(‎‎eta‎‎) ‎-- ‎(‎delta‎)‎;‎‎
‎‎\draw [arrow] ‎(‎nu‎‎‎) ‎-- ‎(‎delta‎)‎;‎‎
‎
%level2‎
‎‎\draw [arrow] ‎(‎‎chi‎) ‎-- ‎(‎tau‎)‎;‎‎
‎‎\draw [arrow] ‎(‎‎theta‎‎) ‎-- ‎(‎tau‎)‎;‎‎
‎
‎‎\draw [arrow] ‎(‎‎eta‎‎) ‎-- ‎(‎delta‎)‎;‎‎
‎‎\draw [arrow] ‎(‎nu‎‎‎) ‎-- ‎(‎delta‎)‎;‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
%%path‎
‎‎
‎‎‎\draw [arrow] ‎(‎‎alpha‎‎) ‎-- ‎(‎resp‎)‎;‎‎
‎‎\draw [‎arrow‎‎‎‎‎‎] ‎(‎tau‎‎‎) ‎-- ‎(‎resp‎‎)‎;‎‎
‎‎\draw [‎arrow‎‎‎] ‎(‎delta‎‎‎) ‎-- ‎(‎resp‎‎)‎;‎‎‎‎
‎
‎\node[‎a‎,fit=(‎resp‎) (tau) (delta)] (container) {‎‎‎‎‎‎}‎;‎‎
‎\node[‎b‎‎,fit=(‎resp‎) (tau) (delta)‎(nu)(mu-nu)(sigma-nu)‎‎] (container) {‎}‎;‎‎
‎\node[‎c‎‎‎,fit=(‎resp‎) (tau) (delta)‎(nu)(‎chi‎)(‎theta‎)(alpha)(eta)‎] (container) {‎}‎;‎‎‎‎
‎
‎\end{tikzpicture}‎
‎\end{document}
```

Now, I would like to add index p = 1,...P, i = 1,...I and j = 1,...J for each plate (red index in the figure is drawn by paint!)

[image]

any help would be appreciated.

P.S.: in addition how can I bold the text in all nodes my one syntax? or any syntax that make them more obvious. For example, arranging all of the prior distributions in a column next to the model.

Comment: Add `font=\bfseries` to the options you pass to `tikzpicture`?

Comment: I think it's not possible to place `labels` inside nodes but you can add new nodes where you need. `\node[above=3mm of container.south] {p index};` could serve you to label third container. Previous syntax is valid if you introduce it after every `container` if you want to add all labels after all `fit` nodes, change their names accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package `tikz-BayesNet` has `\plate` which has as its final argument the text to place within the plate. For example (from Lee and Wagenmakers' Bayesian Cognitive Modeling):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \tikz{
    % nodes
     \node[obs] (x) {$x_i$};%
     \node[latent,above=of x,xshift=-1cm] (mu) {$\mu$}; %
     \node[latent,above=of x] (r) {$r$}; %
     \node[latent,above=of x,xshift=1cm] (sigma) {$\sigma$}; %
    % plate
     \plate [inner sep=.3cm,xshift=.02cm,yshift=.2cm] {plate1} {(x)} {$i$ data}; %
    % edges
     \edge {r,sigma,mu} {x}  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you show an example? As it stands now, this is better-suited as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

By default anchors for label nodes are selected such a way that labels are placed *outside* of labeled nodes.

Once label anchor is selected, label node is placed at `label distance` (0pt by default) from main node. If this distance is negative, labels are moved towards main node center.

This way, all three `fit` nodes can be declared with

```
\node[a, fit=(resp) (tau) (delta), 
      label={[label distance=-7mm, text=red]235:$j=1,\dots,J$}] (container) {};
\node[b, fit=(resp) (tau) (delta) (nu) (mu-nu) (sigma-nu), 
      label={[label distance=-8mm, text=red]230:$i=1,\dots,I$}] (container) {};
\node[c,fit=(resp) (tau) (delta) (nu) (chi) (theta) (alpha) (eta), 
      label={[label distance=-6mm, text=red]270:$p=1,\dots,P$}] (container) {};
```

to obtain

[image]